Oncological applications of a leadership detection algorithm for moving cell populations
In the article ``Detecting switching leadership in collective motion" by Butail and Porfini (2019), the authors propose an algorithmic method to automatically detect leaders among groups of moving animals. The leaders are the invididuals within this group whose movements largely direct the movements of their followers. At the same time, the movements of the followers do not affect the leader's movements.
While tracking animal leadership seems interesting and useful to me in some research or conservation contexts, I have another possible application of this algorithm in mind. I believe this algorithm may also be employed to detect leader cells among cancer populations. Previous academic research has indicated that certain cell types among cancer clads during metastasis (spread to a secondary site within the host's body) act as leaders. For instance, in the work of Saénz-de-Santa-María et al. (2020), the authors show that the presence of leader mesenchymal cells is significantly associated with metastasis development, recurrent disease, and low overall disease survival in head and neck squamous cell carcinomas.
Moreover, in a review article by Qin et al. (2021), the authors note the importance of both leaders and followers in collective cell migration. The leader cells are identified as specialized front cells that assume a ``finger-like" structure. The follower cells comprise the majority of the collective, and are located in the cell reservoir. The authors note that recent studies suggest that not only leader cells, but also follower cells become specialized during the polarization process that enables collective migratory properties. (More information about the role of cell polarity in collective migration can be found here.) Both leader and follower cells are depicted in the image below, which can be found on page 1267 of Qin et al.'s article.
$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad $
Various techniques from automated image analysis have already been employed to spur oncological research. For instance, van Ineveld et al. (2022) describe a number of 3D imaging methods that drive cancer discovery. These include light sheet technology to study blood and lymphatic vasculature. This can be useful, as blood and lymphatic vascular systems provide gateways for whole-body tumour dissemination. Other techniques include whole-body 3 imaging techniques (including CUBIC, 3DISCO, and DeepMACT) allows for the study of late manifestation in cancer, which enables quantification of metastasis. In yet more recent work by Holme et al. (2023), the authors describe a technique to automatically track cell migration in phase contrast images - as opposed to fluorescence images.
I highly the suspect the leadership detection algorithm developed by Butail and Porfini can play a role in cancer research. It can automatically detect leader cells from a series of images of moving cancer cell populations. Unfortunately, I am not a biologist, but a mathematician. I thus find it hard to pinpoint exactly how this algorithm can propel cancer research forwards.
Thus, my question is:

What biological, clinical, or pharmacological applications does a functioning leadership detection algorithm for migrating cancer cell populations have in oncological research?


I don't know that it does - there's no conscious decision in cells migrating, so the "leadership" is unlike that found in a game of soccer/football.

@bob1 True, but cells don't make conscious decisions about most of the things they do, right? Yet it is of importance to be able to understand what mechanisms lie behind cell behaviour, in order to drive biology and pharmacology forwards

How do the papers cited in Qin et al. (2021) identify leaders? Is their method easy or difficult? What sort of data do you need to apply your algorithm? Hours of invasive live-cell imaging? If it's easy or your method is hard, what's the point of an algorithm?

@BryanKrause I've tried contacting a number of the authors cited by Qin et al. Many appear to be busy at the moment - it's still close to the start of the academic year. I believe an algorithm can save time - especially in the long run, when it is improved upon in various various ways (detection of multiple leaders, 3D detection instead of 2D, etc.). It can also potentially identify the moment at which cells become leaders - thus providing more insight in the process of cancer metastasis

@MaxMuller Where are you going to get the 3D data from? You should read the methods sections rather than trying to contact authors.

@BryanKrause There are more and more 3D imaging methods that are employed in oncological research. For instance, in the paper "3D imaging for driving cancer discovery" (2022) van Ineveld et al. name a number of techniques that allow for three dimensional imagery of the human body for cancer research, including light sheet technology, whole-body imaging (CUBIC, 3DISCO, DeepMACT), confocal and multiphoton microscopy, and multi-marker imaging.

@MaxMuller Don't you need 4D imaging?

@BryanKrause Light sheet technology has been applied at a high temporal resolution to be able to observe movements in 3D within organisms, see e.g. "High-contrast single-particle tracking by selective focal plane illumination microscopy" by Ritter et al. (2008)
